Is there a way to let the app go behind the notch in Android phones using Cordova?
My app doesn't go through the notch on Android and i can't find a way to do it.
I've run across this plugin but I still can't figure out how to apply it.
I've been searching for days but I couldn't find anything that actually worked.

The solution was using

app.statusbar.overlaysWebView(true);

using Framework7, right after cordova was done loading the app
